# Two way binding with boolean property

Tags: angular

In Angular two way binding with string property works in following example

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
```

I am trying to use two way binding with boolean property, but it does not work.

```html
<input type="radio" name="isActive" id="isActiveNo" value="0" [(ngModel)]="user.isActive">
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Is it giving you some error? What is happening?

Comment: this is not selecting radio button if value is set to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `[value]` instead of `value`, and the value supposed to be true or false to be boolean.

[Check out simple example](https://plnkr.co/edit/sEwh3Y4lHwBvQugZtYfC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

thanks @omeralper I was able to use your solution.

`<input type="radio" name="isActive" id="isActiveNo" [value]="false" [(ngModel)]="user.isActive">`